# Round a double value up to two decimal places

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have issue that I want to round the double data type to  two decimal places.
I am writing the below apex code to do that but not working.

```
public Double APR_system_Volume_with_Racking_m3_Annual{get;set;}

APR_system_Volume_with_Racking_m3_Annual = ((dBBU_in_MBU * dTotal_Volume_BBU_m3) + dTotal_Volume_MBU_m3)* dMBU; 
      i = APR_system_Volume_with_Racking_m3_Annual * 10;
      APR_system_Volume_with_Racking_m3_Annual = Math.round(i);
      APR_system_Volume_with_Racking_m3_Annual = APR_system_Volume_with_Racking_m3_Annual /10;
```

Still my variable APR_system_Volume_with_Racking_m3_Annual showing value like  33737.670000000006 in my visual force page. I want to format that value in apex not in visual force outputtext formatting like

```
<apexutputText value="{0, number, 000,000.00}">
       <apexaram value="{!Account.AnnualRevenue}" />
</apexutputText>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In Apex try the following code. I hope this should work.

```
Decimal annualRevenue= 0;
annualRevenue= <Calculate your value>;
Account.AnnualRevenue = annualRevenue.SetScale(2); // set the result to 2 decimal places
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.its working fine when data type is decimal but i have my data type as double as i have wrote . because there are more workout on the same variable as well.